# console logging Reduced array returns only the last value

Tags: ecmascript-6, functional-programming

in order to try `reduce` in js, I'm trying to use it to addition 2 arrays values together. I know plenty ways of doing that without reduce, and with reduce as well I thought, but here is the problem : When console logging the reduced array, I only get the last reduced value, and I don't know why.

```
let dblArray = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]

let arr = dblArray[0].reduce((newArr, iter, index) => {
     // this returns 5, 7, 9 as expected
    return iter + dblArray[1][index]
}, [])

console.log(arr) // this returns only 9
```

Can someone tell me why is that ? I'm wondering if my implementation is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `map`? `reduce` is *supposed* to return a single value. Maybe you can show the working code so that we know what you actually want to do.

Comment: Reduce, not map. And this is the whole working code. I accepted the below answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce works by overwriting the previous value with the value returned from the iterator function. Hence when you get to the last iteration, it returns only the last value.

You need to build an array inside the iterator function, joining the previous value and the current value, then return that:

```
let dblArray = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
]

let arr = dblArray[0].reduce((previousArray, iter, index) => {
    // We can use array spread here to join the old array,
    // and add the new value to it
    return [...previousArray, iter + dblArray[1][index]];
    // On each iteration this would log:
    // [5]
    // [5, 7]
    // [5, 7, 9]
}, [])

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get that the previous value was overwritten. It's clearer now :)